# SOAP WCF: Prevent deserialization to private fields

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I am trying to execute SOAP calls from SoapUI, against WCF, and when the XML is being deserialized, it is trying to deserialize to private fields. Why is that happening and how can I get around it?  The code is listed below:

I generated POCO classes from XSD files using the standard XSD.exe and the results look something like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterConfig#")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterConfig#", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MeterConfig
{

    private ComFunction[] comFunctionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ComFunction")]
    public ComFunction[] ComFunction
    {
        get { return this.comFunctionField; }
        set { this.comFunctionField = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a WCF SOAP endpoint as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyApi
{
    [OperationContract]
    public void CreateMeterConfig2(MeterConfig Payload)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

I have a SoapUI test project where I provide the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:CreateMeterConfig2>
         <tem:Payload>

         </tem:Payload>
      </tem:CreateMeterConfig2>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The error I get is:

```
Expecting element 'comFunctionField'
```

Or in full:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-ZA">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Payload. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 13 position 24. 'EndElement' 'Payload' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element 'comFunctionField'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you auto-generated a type marked with [`XmlSerializer`-specific attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but are using WCF which [uses `DataContractSerializer` by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  When [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tries to serialize a type marked with [`[SerializableAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but no [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it infers a contract similar to how `BinaryFormatter` works, namely that public and private fields should be serialized, not properties.  (For more, see [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

To work around this problem, you can:

1. Configure WCF to use `XmlSerializer` by applying [`[XmlSerializerFormatAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) to your service.  To do this, see [How to change Wcf to use a different serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050938/how-to-change-wcf-to-use-a-different-serializer) and [Using the XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.:

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   [XmlSerializerFormat]
   public class MyApi
   {
       [OperationContract]
       public void CreateMeterConfig2(MeterConfig Payload)
       {
           //do nothing
       }
   }
   ```
2. Automatically generate your classes from your XSD with data contract attributes rather than `XmlSerializer` attributes by using `svcutil.exe` rather than `xsd.exe`.  To do this, see [Generate DataContract from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188909/generate-datacontract-from-xsd) and [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

   Note that `DataContractSerializer` has some limitations compared to `XmlSerializer`.  For instance it doesn't allow for properties to be selectively serialized as XML attributes rather than elements.  For more, see [XML Serialisation - When To Use DataContractSerializer / Binary / XMLSerialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977043/xml-serialisation-when-to-use-datacontractserializer-binary-xmlserialiser) or [Data Contract Serializer - How to omit the outer element of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591045/data-contract-serializer-how-to-omit-the-outer-element-of-a-collection).  If your XSD is not compatible with these limitations you will need to use `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: A very thorough answer, thanks.  I've gone with adding [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute] which solves the problem.